# IAM authentication failure into S3, from a Fargate container, using aws-sdk-go

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-go

I'm using the aws-sdk-go library in my go app.

Roughly the code looks like:
 `awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region:aws.String(region)})`
and

```
        upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(filename),
            Body:   bytes.NewReader(fileContents),
        }

        uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(awsSession)

        result, err := uploader.Upload(upParams)
```

When run locally, in a binary, outside a container, this works, because it reads my keys from ~/.aws/credentials.

When run locally, in a Docker container, this works, because I pass in ~/.aws/credentials via `$HOME/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro` when starting the container.

But when I tell Fargate to fetch the container from ECR (which works), and run it, it gives these errors in the Task log:

- `Failed to upload files to S3`
- `For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors`
- `Failed to upload file: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.`

I assume I'm supposed to rely on an IAM policy for the Fargate-managed container/task to get read/write access to S3.

I tried going to IAM -> Roles -> ecsTaskExecutionRole, and adding the AmazonS3FullAccess role, then stopping the task (& having Fargate re-start it). But I get the same error.

I assume I either need to change the Golang code to somehow read the creds from IAM, instead of a file, or I'm doing something wrong on the IAM or Fargate/ECS side.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the problem is a misconception, we have the `executionRoleArn` and `taskRoleArn` as properties in the task definition. When you launch a new task you need the `executionRoleArn`, but for use aws-sdk you need to pass a `taskRoleArn`.

You need to attach s3 policies in the `taskRoleArn`.